# Only keeping a certain number of rows having a particular value in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Part of my dataframe `df` looks as follows. This is how it looks after I use `df = df.drop_duplicates('months_to_maturity')`. However, now, for each row having the same `months_to_maturity` I want to keep `number_of_rows_for_each_maturity` many rows having this particular maturity.

```
   months_to_maturity                      orig_iss_dt  \
1                   6                    2015-06-25 00:00:00.0   
2                  12                    2015-06-25 00:00:00.0   
3                  18                    2015-06-30 00:00:00.0   
4                  24                    2015-06-15 00:00:00.0   
5                  30                    2015-06-30 00:00:00.0   

             maturity_dt  pay_freq_cd  coupon  closing_price  FACE_VALUE  
1  2015-12-24 00:00:00.0          NaN   0.000      99.960889         100  
2  2016-06-23 00:00:00.0          NaN   0.000      99.741444         100  
3  2017-06-30 00:00:00.0            2   0.625      99.968750         100  
4  2018-06-15 00:00:00.0            2   1.125     100.390625         100  
5  2020-06-30 00:00:00.0            2   1.625      99.984375         100
```

I do this with the code below where `pairwise(df.iterrows())` gives the current and next row of the dataframe. *My problem is that I am reading in the dataframe from an Excel document with 600,000 lines and was therefore wondering if there is a better way to do this.*

```
number_of_rows_for_each_maturity = number_of_columns_and_rows/60
count = 0
        for (i1, row1), (i2, row2) in pairwise(df.iterrows()):
            if row1['months_to_maturity'] == row2['months_to_maturity'] and count < number_of_rows_for_each_maturity + 1:
                count = count + 1
            if row1['months_to_maturity'] == row2['months_to_maturity'] and count == number_of_rows_for_each_maturity + 1:
                df.drop(df.index[i1])
            if row1['months_to_maturity'] != row2['months_to_maturity']:
                count = 0
```

Thank You

Comment: Can you just `df.groupby('months_to_maturity').apply(len)` before you drop the duplicates?

Comment: @chrisaycock Thanks. I am just trying to understand what `len` means in your statement above.

Comment: @user131983 It means the Python built-in function.  `len(df)` returns the number of rows in a DataFrame.

Comment: You can also do ```df.groupby('months_to_maturity').size()```